# Very Simple Ajax Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am just learning JQuery and have a few scripts successfully working on my site. Until I get to what the JQuery for nitwits book calls Ajax.  I am trying to do this very simple script

```
<div class="menu">
<script>
$(function(){
$('div').load('mytext.txt');
});
</script>

<div id="here"> </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this on pages where JQuery works just fine so I know my link to google works.  I have tried a couple small scripts like this one and cannot get them to work under any circumstances. Mytext.txt is in the same directory as the php file with the script. Is there some magic word you have to use in order to make .load work?

I have tried

```
$('div#here').load('mytext.txt');
```

to no avail.  Of special note this is on a codeigniter site, but that shouldn't matter being as I am calling ajax independent of the controller and straight from the views like any other JQuery call.

This should be the simplest thing in the world. Why can I not do anything to get .load to work?
Thanks

Comment: can you access mytext.txt from the browser?

Comment: I will try to use php include to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working along the lines you gave - see a working jsfiddle here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/PuPtT/

The only thing I can think of is to check the path to the file (maybe it should be `/mytext.txt`, i.e. with a slash in front). Also, can you open the file from within your browser, i.e. browse to `www.yoursite.com/mytext.txt`?

As a side note, `<script>` tags should generally go to `<head>` element in your HTML.

Comment: I cant address the file directly because of the file conventions with codeigniter.  I can call it using php include

Comment: Ok I got it to work by moving the file I want to include all the way out to the public_html directory.  I shoudnt have had to but will continue to figure out why that would matter.  Thanks to all of you, you are great people

Comment: Np, glad to help! Anyway, if it was just the path, then, depending on your setup, you should be able to get it using the whole path (with the old location of the file). E.g. if the file is in `public_html/a/b/c/mytext.txt`, you should be able to use `/a/b/c/mytext.txt` to get to it (and you can check that from within your browser).

Answer (score 2):

Try running your page using Firefox with Firebug enabled; and watch the NET/HTTP traffic.

My guess is that there is a relative path issue; but Firebug should give you some more detail as to what the exact error is when mytext.txt is requested.

Comment: I get the message that $(function is not defined, and there is no call to the file mytext.txt

Comment: I am using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> I will add a link to the onsite jquery

Comment: Ok now getting a mytext.txt not found.  Let me move it around

Comment: @brad, this is certainly a path issue. browsers handle relative paths differently (grrr). To confirm this, first try an absolute url (rooted '/serverroot/path/to/text.txt') to the text file. solutions to this is to either use rooted paths (bad solution, not portable, makes deployment complicated) or figure out why your relative path is not working the same in all browsers (need to post the directory structure) or use js browser sniffing hacks to adjust the url (smelly like week old tuna can)

Comment: Sky I got it figured out, for some reason it wouldnt recognize the file as being in the same directory.  So I moved it out of the codeigniter directory and to the root and it worked perfectly.  That was just my first (and last to date) effort with ajax. You are right, it was path related. TY

Answer (score 1):

This following snippet is working correctly on my Linux hosting environment. Both of the files (so.html and mytext.txt are located in the document root.) I wonder if not specifying the "type" attribute with the script tag is causing you some issues. You also want to make sure to qualify the div selector as well: $('div#here').load... as opposed to $('div').load...

**File = /so.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stackoverflow is Awesome</title>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="here"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('div#here').load('mytext.txt');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**File = /mytext.txt**

Hello from mytext.txt!!!!!

Comment: I believe the code is good.  However Chrome and firefox firebug tells me the file cant be found.  As well as firefox telling me the $document ready is not defined.  I am going to work on file positions and rename the file to an html file.  As this is codigniter I thinkI will need to find where its looking for the file as nothing I do seems to pick up the file that does exist